# Contoller action without path in ruby on rails - is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I am quite new to Ruby and probably doing smth incorrect but how to make a controller action without a route??

I need this controller ONLY FOR REDIRECT from another controllers.
See below

```
  def redirect_to_correct_stage
case @lession_stats.stage
  when 'stage1'
    puts "Redirecting to stage1"
    redirect_to :action => :stage1
    return
  when 'stage2'
    puts "Redirecting to stage2"
    redirect_to :action => :stage2
    return
  when 'stage3'
    puts "Redirecting to stage3"
    redirect_to :action => :stage3
    return
  else
    redirect_to root_path, :alert => t(:error_unknown_stage)
end
```

end

My main action is redirect_to_correct_stage and have correct path ('/word') and I need to redirect it to correct actions based on model value.

Everything works fine but now person can move directly to stage3 using ('/stage3')
Of course I could add more checks in stage3 action but I dont want to check twice.

What should I do?

Comment: If you just need to call additional logic for say `stage2` then why not just have a protected method on your controller, call that, then redirect accordingly at the end of the controller method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A controller action is a method with a route, an entry point to your application. If you are do add a method without a route it cannot be called with a web request.